# Identifying molecule with three adjacent six-membered rings from blurry image

Tags: molecular-structure, molecules, identification

I have found this isolated image on one of my old hard drives and I would like to know what molecule does the image represent:

[image: Unknown chemical structure]

Comment: Hint: It's a pothead tattoo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be [Δ⁹-tetrahydrocannabinol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahydrocannabinol), also known as Δ⁹-THC:

> [image: 2D structure of tetrahydrocannabidiol (THC)]

(Image source: [2D structure of tetrahydrocannabidiol (THC) by Harbin](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:THC.svg) (Wikimedia))

The comment by [The_Vinz](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/32223/the-vinz) about “*pothead tattoo*” was very … insightful.